# Can anyone tell me why this mouse move doesn't work for the right hand side?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, mousemove

I have a DOM that looks like

outer nav 100% x 100%
nav left 100% x 50%
nav right 100% x 50%
end outer nav

I have added this code to each

```
 $("<img src='/img/next.png' id='next' alt='Next Image' style='display:none;'/>").appendTo(".image-nav .image-nav-right");
        this.$('image-nav-right').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).bind('mousemove', function(event){
                    $("#prev").hide();
                    $('#next').css({
                       left:  event.pageX,
                       top:   event.pageY,
                       position: "absolute",
                       display:"block",
                       "z-index":"30000"
                    });
                });
        });
        $("<img src='/img/prev.png' id='prev' alt='Previous Image' style='display:none;'/>").appendTo(".image-nav .image-nav-left");
        this.$('image-nav-left').mouseover(function() {
                $(this).bind('mousemove', function(event){
                    $("#next").hide();
                    $('#prev').css({
                       left:  event.pageX,
                       top:   event.pageY-25,
                       position: "absolute",
                       display:"block",
                       "z-index":"30000"
                    });
                });
        });
```

All the containers have a position absolute, and the left mouseover works wonderfully but the right mouseover displays about 800px off screen to the right. I'm not sure why, everything is being hovered properly, I checked with console.

I was thinking the pageX and pageY aren't reset? or the right image isn't positioning absolute to the div, but to the window..

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you create this as a js fiddle? May be easier to debug

Comment: I don't understand why you are binding `mousemove` when the `mouseover` event fires. Why does the `.hover()` JQuery method not work for you here?

Comment: I need to get the position of the mouse and bind the image left and image right to the mouseposition, but if your over left div, hide next image and if your over right div, hide prev image

Answer (score 0):

First of all ..

`this.$('image-nav-right')` and `this.$('image-nav-left')` should probably be

`$('.image-nav-right')` and `$('.image-nav-left')` (*removed `this.` and added `.` to the class selectors*)

Then, you really do not need the `mouseover` events.. just bind directly to the `mousemove` (*otherwise you bind multiple times the event handler of `mousemove` and that can mess things up*)

so.. more like

```
$("<img src='/img/next.png' id='next' alt='Next Image' style='display:none;'/>").appendTo(".image-nav .image-nav-right");
        $('.image-nav-right').bind('mousemove', function(event){
                $("#prev").hide();
                $('#next').css({
                   left:  event.pageX,
                   top:   event.pageY,
                   position: "absolute",
                   display:"block",
                   "z-index":"30000"
                   });
        });
$("<img src='/img/prev.png' id='prev' alt='Previous Image' style='display:none;'/>").appendTo(".image-nav .image-nav-left");
        $('.image-nav-left').mousemove(function(event){
                    $("#next").hide();
                    $('#prev').css({
                       left:  event.pageX,
                       top:   event.pageY-25,
                       position: "absolute",
                       display:"block",
                       "z-index":"30000"
                    });
        });
```

Comment: Didn't work :(, the reason for the this.$('image-nav-right') etc is because it's all contained within an external function. Thanks anyway for the solution :)

Comment: @Tara, can you post in your question the HTML and CSS ?

Comment: I got it working, forgot to minus half the page from the div on the right's position, -.-